# Looking for way to add sum of cells based on value of adjacent cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

Apologies for the confusing title. What I'm trying to do is better explained visually. Here is my main table where users will be entering information:

**Base Table**

[image]

In the Defect Code Column, there is a specific list of codes that can be entered. These go from A1-A15, B1-B14, C1-C10, etc. After the user enters a defect code, they will enter a qty to the right of it. What I need is a function to be able to go through each column, find each specific defect code, add up the qty that is to the right of them and then spit the total out into a cell. There is no guarantee that any defect will be found in a tray and there's no guarantee that they will be input into the table in alphanumeric order. Is Excel capable of doing something like this or do I have to change my approach?

Here's what I would like the end result table to look like:

**End Results Table**

[image]

Comment: i think you're looking for the sumif function documented here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=LET(
arrayDefectCode,VSTACK($C$2:$C$11,$E$2:$E$11,$G$2:$G$11,$I$2:$I$11),
arrayQty,VSTACK($B$2:$B$11,$D$2:$D$11,$F$2:$F$11,$H$2:$H$11),
mySum,SUM(FILTER(arrayDefectCode,K2=arrayQty,0)),
IF(mySum=0,"",mySum))
```

Copy the formula to every cell in the columns Qty

[image: Excel screenshot of data with formula]

Comment: I tried copying this exactly and am getting a #NAME? error unfortunately

Comment: What version of Excel do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this using a **custom**, **reusable** functions and call them by a **friendly** name using `LAMBDA()`

[image]

---

• Firstly goto **Formulas Tab** --> Click on **Name Manager** --> Click **New**

• **Name** --> `QTY_SUM`

• **Scope** --> `Workbook`

---

```
=LAMBDA(_array,_lookup,
LET(a,_array, b,SORT(WRAPROWS(TOCOL(a),2),1),
BYROW(_lookup,LAMBDA(x,SUM((x=TAKE(b,,1))*TAKE(b,,-1))))))
```

---

• Now use the formula in cells `L2`

```
=QTY_SUM(B2:I11,K2:K16)
```

---

When you type the custom function in the cells it will show as with the syntax

[image]

---

**Syntax:**

```
=QTY_SUM(_array,_lookup)
```

---

Change the ranges for `N2` & `P2` as `M2:M16` & `O2:O16`. However, it's based on my worksheet, you may need to change all the ranges accordingly as per your suit.

---

Comment: I follow the steps for this method but I'm not getting the syntax to pop up when I type =QTY_SUM( . I also get a #NAME? error with this.

Comment: Hey there @Brandon, thanks for your response. May I know what is your `Excel` Version? This is because the mentioned formulas here works with `MS365` Exclusively. Also `#NAME?` appears when there is `typo` or the said `Function` is not available in your version of `Excel`. More on **[#NAME?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-name-error-b6d54e31-a743-4d7d-9b61-40002a7b4286)** error